# Border inside an image with margin

Tags: image, css, margin

how can I achieve this effect with CSS:

[image]

Do I need a smaller Div with a margin and a border or is this somehow possible using box-shadow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need a single element with :before or :after  all is up to you

the Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6a95A/1/

the markup:

```
<figure></figure>
```

[image]

the style

```
figure{
    width:200px;
    height: 180px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2scelXYGA1qbmtexo1_500.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50%;
}
figure:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 2%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would set it as a `background-image` and place it within an outer `div`, `.img` in this example. Then add `padding`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Then add an inner `div` that would provide the border, `.border` in this example.

**CSS**

```
.img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200');
}
.border {
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 190px;
}
```

**NOTE**: The `height` of `.border` includes both the `5px` for each top and bottom `border`.

So **(** `200px` for the `img` **+** `10px` for both top and bottom `border` **)**  **-** `20px` for top and bottom `padding` = `190px`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Yy2/)**

---

**Update**

If you want `%` values rather than fixed, you can modify your CSS in `.border { .. }` to this:

```
.border {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Yy2/3/)**

Comment: I wouldn't set the height of the border to 190, but rathet 100%. It looks a bit fishy in your fiddle. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Yy2/1/) seems to be better distributed

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work with box shadow maybe something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HgxbM/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aYLD.jpg" />
    <span class="border"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:302px;
    height:187px;
}
.border {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    display:block;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

or with using `CSS calc()` http://jsfiddle.net/HgxbM/4/

```
.border {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    display:block;
    border:solid 1px red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions seem a bit better, but might just post it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HbcRp/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="border">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (note: the background-color is there just for demonstration):

```
.image {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:none;
    padding:none;
}
.border {
    border: solid white 1px;
    height:110px;
    width:260px;
    margin:20px auto auto auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one avenue, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lpssz/1/
The HTML:

```
<div class="picture" 
     style="background-image: url(YourPicture.jpg); height: 200px; width: 200px;">
<div class="borderbox"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:
    .picture {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    }
    .borderbox {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    }

With this, you are applying the image as the background element of the div, then creating an extra div within the 'image div' that creates the internal border. the 'image div' is formatting the placement of the border by use of its padding attribute, and the internal border div is stretching to fill the rest of the space.