# set inner shadow border to be ontop of image inside div

Tags: css, html, border, shadow

I want a border inside the div display when an image is hover, but its showing the border on the back side of the div. I tried using z-index but doesnt work either.  here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/ormxn1dn/2/

```
.thumb_images{
float:left;
width: 90px;
height: 60px;
background-color:#CCC;
text-align:center;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.thumb_images:hover{
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
}
    <div id="thumb0" class="thumb_images">
        <img src="http://img.yapo.cl/thumbs/70/7034297379.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="thumb1" class="thumb_images">
        <img src="http://img.yapo.cl/thumbs/70/7015566906.jpg">
    </div>      
    <div id="thumb2" class="thumb_images">
        <img src="http://img.yapo.cl/thumbs/70/7058183501.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: i dont see any code for border in css ? And border in never inside of div its always outside of element(i.e div)

Comment: I did a border using shadow since border its always outside. the problem is that shadow border is only showing on the backside of the img inside the div but i need it to be on the top.

Comment: Possible duplicated, you can do it border and :before, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595760/border-inside-an-image-with-margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do...

https://jsfiddle.net/hs5g1osv/1/

```
.thumb_images {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb_images img {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: border .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .15s ease-in-out;
}

.thumb_images img:hover {
    border-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Is not exactly what i was looking for but upvote for the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you wrapping the images in a div?  Why are you using box-shadow to make a border?

You can just apply the styles right to the images themselves.  You can then just add a border on hover.

I can write it up for you if you need me to.  I just need a bit more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: each div contains a data id  when click i get the data id which has url to the big image and shows it on another div on top. I just like to show border inside the div when hover on a thumb and also when is selected, this is not dificult but the problem im having a hard time showing the border on top of the image.  here is the fiddle to see code working without images https://jsfiddle.net/ormxn1dn/3/

Comment: Thank you to whoever downvoted me for trying to get more information to answer the question.

Comment: @SeanStopnik That's the reason questions support comments

Comment: Don't be discouraged by that down vote, the important thing is that you were trying to help. Let's just try to keep things organized. :)